# New Mac JFileChooser solution after death of Quaqua on Mavericks

Tags: java, macos, swing, look-and-feel

It looks like [Werner Randelshofer's fine Quaqua Look-and-feel for Java Swing over Mac OS X](http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/index.html) has been orphaned for Mavericks.  Is there any alternative or forked effort to continue updates, especially for the `JFileChooser` replacement?

Comment: I like `java.awt.FileDialog`, but a custom [`FileBrowser`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446) is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fork of the project which does support Mavericks: https://github.com/karlvr/Quaqua

By "support", I simply mean that it doesn't explode when you try to use it. The file chooser does work. Most other custom UIs still work, but (AFAIK) have not been updated at all.

Comment: Thanks. I found this too.  On my app at least it turned out the FileChooser worked okay under Mavericks without this port.  If you have been able to "blow up" Werner's `filechooser-only.jar` under Mavericks I would appreciate knowing how you did it.

Comment: Actually, I haven't tried the filechooser-only version (because what I'm trying to get all of it to work so that I can have correct component spacing and so forth.) So that part of it might actually be fine. When I tried to use the normal Quaqua jar, the decoration on most components completely disappeared. My uneducated guess was that it was detecting my OS as the highest known (10.7) and then trying to paint the stuff using routines which no longer work in 10.9.

Answer (score 0):

i had some problems with the JFileChooser following solves my problems:

Add a Thread.sleep(500) before you call JFilerChooser.showOpenDialog

```
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {

    }
    if (o_JFileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
```

.....